# Why Ansible needs modules?

Tags: ansible

From Ansible documentation - modules are small programs which Ansible uploads to target system, executes them and deletes upon completion.

But why Ansible needs them in the first place? For example, I want to execute several commands on Cisco switch. In a playbook I will have to use ios_config module. But why Ansible can't establish ssh connection to the switch and start pushing commands to the console? What module is doing there?

Sorry for probably "naive" question, but I didn't find an explanation in Ansible documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible at its most basic, provides a method for users to describe the state that a system should be in. Ansible then compares the existing state of the system, to the state that the user has described, and where they don't match, takes the necessary action to resolve the difference.

Crucially, this behavior means that Ansible can be run against a system any number of times, and it will only make changes when they are necessary (typically the first time the playbook is applied to a target). Therefore there is more going on than simply applying a series of commands.

A module packages up a particular task and takes responsibility for:

- Providing a consistent method for a user to describe the intended state of the system, in terms of the feature the module targets
- Handles checking the target system to determine whether the system state matches that requested by the user, for the feature the module targets
- Only if necessary, changes the target system to match the state requested by the user, for the feature the module targets

The fact that Ansible exposes a consistent API for creating modules, means that Ansible is endlessly extensible, and so it is possible to add new modules to Ansible, for features that are not currently supported.

You specifically mention `ios_config`. Network devices are a slightly strange category of devices, because historically they have not really been designed in such a way that makes them easy to be accessed by automation. Therefore if that is the only category of system you have used Ansible with, it can be a little less clear why the general approach Ansible takes, and modules more specifically, are so useful.

Away from network devices, Ansible, through the module system, is capable of configuring pretty much any aspect of a computer system, and as such reduces management of very different tools and techniques, into a consistent API for end users.